# Heap Corruption detected

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

This is the way that i have alocated the memory.

```
Expression = new char[MemBlock.length()];
VarArray = new char[Variables.length()];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < MemBlock.length(); i++)
{
    Expression[i] = MemBlock.at(i);
}
Expression[MemBlock.length() + 1] = NULL;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Variables.length(); i++)
{
    VarArray[i] = Variables.at(i);
}
VarArray[Variables.length() + 1] = NULL;
```

when i try to delete it i get the error...

```
Logic::~Logic(){
delete[] VarArray;  -> happens on this line.
VarArray = NULL;
delete[] Expression;
Expression = NULL;
}
```

in the entire code i dont not make any changes to the new array yet it tells me i hame some currpution, i cant pin point the problem , any help would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`VarArray[Variables.length() + 1] = NULL;`

accesses memory you do not own since this array is allocated thus:

`VarArray = new char[Variables.length()];`

The final element in this array has index `Variables.length() - 1`.

Running this in a debugger ought be be instructive. Some static analysis tools (eg. lint) would highlight this misuse, I believe.

You could also consider using [boost::scoped_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) or similar to remove the need for manual deletion. A good lesson to learn early on for C++ is to adopt [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) instead of manual memory management, wherever you can.

Answer (score 2):

```
VarArray = new char[Variables.length()];
VarArray[Variables.length() + 1] = NULL;
```

You can´t do that, it´s 2 elements to much.
Same for the other array.

Answer (score 1):

```
Expression[MemBlock.length() + 1] = NULL;
```

Is Undefined Behavior.  As is

```
VarArray[Variables.length() + 1] = NULL;
```

In the 1st case you can only index up to `MemBlock.length() - 1`, and in the 2nd case `Variables.length() - 1`.

In both cases you are writing past the end of the allocated array and are probably overwriting the control structures used (by the runtime library) to manage dynamically allocated memory.